# What will be SQL query to find common values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `RoleRights` with column `RoleId` and `RightId`.
Lets say table has data as below :

```
----------------------
| RoleId  | RightId  |
----------------------
| Role1   | Right1   |
| Role2   | Right2   |
| Role3   | Right3   |
| Role2   | Right1   |
----------------------
```

What will be the query to find common `Rights` between two `Roles` ?
E.g. I want to find out rights common between `Role1` & `Role2` .

Comment: union and union all!!!!

Comment: Tushar, you've asked what happens if there are more than two roles. If there were three roles, and a right was in two of the roles but not the third, do you want to see it?  ie, does any duplicate count, or does it need to duplicate in all the roles?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've asked for handling it for n number of roles, you can achieve it using the following query.

```
SELECT right_column
FROM your_table
WHERE role_column IN ('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3') -- Roles selected
GROUP BY right_column HAVING count(1) = 3 -- total number of roles selected
```

If you've duplicate role-right entry, you can try

```
;with cte as 
(
    select distinct role_column , right_column 
    from your_table
    where role_column in ('Role1','Role2','Role3')
)
select right_column 
from cte
group by right_column 
having count(1) = 3
```

Comment: Topicstarter most likly you would need to use a DISTINCT in the count instead like `Having Count(DISTINCT role_column) = 3` to make sure the roles are unique

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to check more than 2 roles at once (as noted in some of the comments) then you could do this

```
With basedata as
(
    Select distinct RoleID, RightID   -- ignore duplicates of the same role/right
    from YourTable
    Where RoleID in ('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3')  --List all roleIDs to check here
)
Select RightID, Count(RoleID) as RCount
From basedata
Group by RightID
Having Count(RoleID) > 1
```

This would show all rights in at least 2 roles. If a right had to be in all the roles to show up, change the last row  to

```
Having Count(*) = 3  --set this to number of roles you're checking
```

Comment: Topicstarter most likly you would need to use a DISTINCT in the count instead like `Having Count(DISTINCT RoleID) = 3` to make sure the roles are unique.